# How do I automatically start the Python Indent plugin in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, plugins

I am using Notepad++ with the Python Indent plugin installed to automatically indent the code. However, every time I start Notepad++, the plugin is disabled and I have to go the the plugin menu and enable it from there.

Is there a way to automatically enable it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start (one time) with administrative privileges and enable it. If you exit Notepad++ it will be saved.

I analysed the source code of this plugin and I've seen that it is disabled by default. So I changed this default setting and put it to [github](https://github.com/renpe/kereds-notepad-plus-plus-plugins).
You can download the new plugin [directly here](https://github.com/renpe/kereds-notepad-plus-plus-plugins/raw/master/bin/Python%20Indent.dll). Just copy it to your Notepad++\plugins directory.